# Trouble with JSON Data taken from localStorage in JavaScript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am making a completely offline HTML5 web app.

In a particular part of my code, I am required to add a row of data to a JavaScript Array Object and save the updated version back to `localStorage`.

Here is the code:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("cars");

//Trouble in this line.
data.goals.push(["name": "merscede", "model": "bmw", "noofdays": "10", "active": "yes"]); 

localStorage.setItem("goals",data);
```

And this is the value I had stored in the localStorage in a different part of the source code:

```
var data = '{"goals":[{"name":"rocky","model":"old","noofdays":"50","active":"no"}]}';
localStorage.setItem("goals",data);
```

I have troubleshooted extensively and it turns out that only the line that I have particularly marked has all the trouble.

What's the problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you need to do it :

```
var data = '{"goals":[{"name":"rocky","model":"old","noofdays":"50","active":"no"}]}';
localStorage.setItem("goals",data);

// You get a string when you do "getItem"
var goalsStr = localStorage.getItem("goals");

// You need to parse it.
var goalsObj = JSON.parse(goalsStr);
goalsObj.goals.push({"name": "merscede", "model": "bmw", "noofdays": "10", "active": "yes"});
console.log(goalsObj);
```

Comment: No need to use localStorage.setItem() again?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to do that in case you want your newly added object to be stored in `localStorage`. You can store it this way :  `localStorage.setItem("goals", JSON.stringify(goalsObj));`. Inside `localStorage` you just store key-value pairs and values must be strings.

Comment: I am getting "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token A" in the console.

Comment: Also, I am not able to get individual values such as goalsObj[1].duedate; and manipulate them. What's wrong?

Comment: `goalsObj` is not an array rather `goals` property in it is an array so `goalsObj.goals[1]` will give you the object you are looking for. Also, there is no `duedate` property in above example.

Comment: What about the "Uncaught Syntaxt Error:...." that I am getting against the line: console.log(goalsObj);

Comment: I could not see a reason for this error. Anyways, just remove that line, it was used to just log the object.